# if statement error while running source ~/.bashrc error

Tags: node.js, linux, bash

I tried running `source ~/.bashrc` but it shows

```
~/.bashrc (line 5): Missing end to balance this if statement
if  [ -x /usr/bin/starship ]; then
^
from sourcing file ~/.bashrc
source: Error while reading file “/home/alokjha/.bashrc”
```

How do i solve it?

I am currently on Garuda Linux (arch linux distro) and new in this linux universe, I want to install nvm, i followed steps as written in https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm. I am not familiar with bash language so kindly help please ( Restart PC or Terminal is't helping)

Edit: Complete BashRc file

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[[ $- != *i* ]] && return

# Load starship prompt if starship is installed
if  [ -x /usr/bin/starship ]; then
    __main() {
        local major="${BASH_VERSINFO[0]}"
        local minor="${BASH_VERSINFO[1]}"

        if ((major > 4)) || { ((major == 4)) && ((minor >= 1)); }; then
            source <("/usr/bin/starship" init bash --print-full-init)
        else
            source /dev/stdin <<<"$("/usr/bin/starship" init bash --print-full-init)"
        fi
    }
    __main
    unset -f __main
fi

# Advanced command-not-found hook
source /usr/share/doc/find-the-command/ftc.bash

# Aliasessource ~/.bashrc error
alias dir='dir --color=auto'
alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
alias fixpacman="sudo rm /var/lib/pacman/db.lck"
alias grep='grep --color=auto'
alias grubup="sudo update-grub"
alias hw='hwinfo --short'
alias psmem10='ps auxf | sort -nr -k 4 | head -10'
alias psmem='ps auxf | sort -nr -k 4'
alias rmpkg="sudo pacman -Rdd"
alias tarnow='tar -acf '
alias untar='tar -zxvf '
alias upd='/usr/bin/update'
alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'
alias wget='wget -c '

# Help people new to Arch
alias apt-get='man pacman'
alias apt='man pacman'
alias helpme='cht.sh --shell'
alias please='sudo'
alias tb='nc termbin.com 9999'

# Cleanup orphaned packages
alias cleanup='sudo pacman -Rns `pacman -Qtdq`'

# Get the error messages from journalctl
alias jctl="journalctl -p 3 -xb"

# Recent installed packages
alias rip="expac --timefmt='%Y-%m-%d %T' '%l\t%n %v' | sort | tail -200 | nl"

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

Comment: I assume that you do not use `bash`. You probably use `fish`.

Comment: so how can use bash (i am asking for running source command)

Comment: @AlokJha The point of `source` is to run the script *in the current shell*. If the current shell is fish, then you can't run bash scripts in it. You could start a bash shell and run the script in that, but it'd defeat the point of `source`. So, the question is, why are you trying to `source` your .bashrc file? What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: Do `echo $SHELL`.  If it does not return bash, start one by typing `bash`.  That should execute your .bashrc automatically, but if you want to source it, you will be able to.

Comment: @Nic3500 `echo $SHELL` is not a reliable way to find out what shell you're using. It (generally) shows the shell that's set as default for the current user account, but that may not be what's actually in use. `ps $$` is more reliable (though it can be confusing too).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem.
First I want to make it clear that I am a newbie in Arch and Garuda, so maybe some of my statements are not entirely correct.

Just as someone told you in the comments, you are using fish, look at the title of the Konsole window. Or edit the `.bashrc` file and set the `if` to fish syntax (change `fi` to `end`) and you'll see that the next error tells you clearly that you are using fish.

### Quick "fix"

Switch to bash by running `bash`, then you can run `source ~/.bashrc`.

The problem with this is that if you exit bash (by executing `exit`) and return to fish, you lose what you get by executing `source ~/.bashrc`. I mean, you have to keep working in bash.

### Solutions without switching to bash

Use [nvm.fish](https://github.com/jorgebucaran/nvm.fish).

Or convert the lines you need (the last 3 of your bashrc file) [to fish syntax](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/tutorial.html#exports-shell-variables), and add them to the `~/.config/fish/config.fish` file, then run `source ~/.config/fish/config.fish`.